# Read a config file into 2D array

Tags: bash

I have a config file:

```
map_a 1234,3788,9940
map_b 9948,8901
map_c
map_d 7789,30400
map_e 499423
map_f
```

The array variable should content:

```
Name    Attribute 1     Attribute 2     Attribute 3     Attribute ...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
map_a   1234            3788            9940            
map_b   9948            8901    
map_c   
map_d   7789            30400
map_e   499423      
map_f
...
```

So:

```
 foo[0,0] = map_a
 foo[0,1] = 1234
 foo[3,2] = 30400
```

...

How can I achieve this with bash? Or are there recommendations for change the delimiters of the .cfg file? As it's flexible from scratch

Regards
Joe C.

Comment: The target is: 
Read the name map_a, do something with it and inside after that read the numbers and do something with it for each number.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add more clear details in your post and let us know then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash arrays are one-dimensional, but associate arrays may allow you to represent something that looks like 2D array (each key will be the indices combined with ','). Without changing the structure:

```
#! /bin/bash
declare -A foo
n=0
maxcol=0
IFS=" ,"
while read k v ; do
    foo[$n,0]=$k
    IFS=', ' read -r -a vv <<< "$v"
    i=1
    for v1 in ${vv[*]} ; do
        foo[$n,$i]=$v1
        [ $i -gt $maxcol ]  && maxcol=$i
        let i=i+1
    done
    let n=n+1
done < config.txt
for ((i=0; i<n ; i++)) do
    for ((j=0 ; j<maxcol ; j++)) do
        echo "foo($i,$j)=${foo[$i,$j]}"
    done
    echo
done
```

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I wanted to do! Simple, clean and mostly understandable by me.
I'll go ahead and figure out the unknown stuff for me, that is
"read command, the <<< and the usage of IFS"

For j<4 instead of 4 I'll do a length control with j<${foo[$i,@]} I hope as the attributes may be more than 4.

THX! @dash-o

Comment: Note that you can not extract the length of a specific entry. The data is placed into a map, with no relationship between elements. Can you calculate the maximum number of attributes (across all entries) in the read loop. See maxcol is revised solution

Comment: To make it simpler to read - I've split the alternative solution into different answer. If any of the solutions works for you, consider accepting it.

Comment: For IFS=, this allowed you to temporary use different separator to break the value list  (1234,2345,3456) into tokens. By default, 'read' will separate on while spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative will be to use the attribute name as the first key, so that it will be possible to query ${foo[map_a,2}} - 2nd attribute of map_a

```
#! /bin/bash
declare -A foo
n=0
maxcol=0
maxcol=0
IFS=" ,"
while read k v ; do
        foo[$n,0]=$k
        IFS=', ' read -r -a vv <<< "$v"
        i=1
        for v1 in ${vv[*]} ; do
                # Use key as first index
                foo[$k,$i]=$v1
                [ $i -gt $maxcol ]  && maxcol=$i
                let i=i+1
        done
        let n=n+1
done < config.txt
for i in map_a map_b map_c map_d map_e map_f ; do
        for ((j=0 ; j<maxcol ; j++)) do
                echo "foo($i,$j)=${foo[$i,$j]}"
        done
        echo
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've also put maxcol into an array:

```
declare -A foo
declare -A maxcol
n=0
IFS=" ,"
while read k v
do
    foo[$n,0]=$k
    IFS=', ' read -r -a vv <<< "$v"
    i=1
    for v1 in ${vv[*]}
    do
        foo[$n,$i]=$v1
        let i=i+1
    done
    maxcol[$n]=$i
    let n=n+1
done < config.txt

for (( i=0; i<n; i++ ))
do
    for (( j=0 ; j<maxcol[$i] ; j++ ))
    do
        echo "foo($i,$j)=${foo[$i,$j]}"
    done
    echo "maxcol($i)=${maxcol[$i]}"
    echo
done
```

I think this will fit my needs now perfectly.